Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' when using langchain document loader
I'm trying to implement langchain in my React webapp. How can I resolve this ERROR in ./node_modules/pdf-parse/lib/pdf.js/v1.10.100/build/pdf.js 17187:13-26 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in <LOCAL_PATH>. Thanks in advance.
Solution tried but not useful:
 "browser": {
    "fs": false
  },

Code:
import { WebPDFLoader } from "@langchain/community/document_loaders/web/pdf";
const blob = new Blob();
const loader = new WebPDFLoader(blob);
const docs = await loader.load();
console.log({ docs });

